# In wp_nav_menu How Move items_wrap to the End

Tags: wordpress, menu

**I have this Code:**

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s"><li><a href="http://www.google.com">go to google</a></li>%3$s</ul>' ) );
```

**The Result:**

```
<ul id="" class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li> // Extra Nav

    <li id="menu-item-5724" class="menu-item"><a href="link">WP Nav Example</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-5725" class="menu-item"><a href="link">Example 2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

**I want to Move Extra menu, to the end:**

```
<ul id="" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-5724" class="menu-item"><a href="link">WP Nav Example</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-5725" class="menu-item"><a href="link">Example 2</a> </li>

    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li> // Extra Nav
</ul>
```

How can i solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$2<li><a href="http://www.google.com">go to google</a></li></ul>'
) );
```

The `%3$2` represents all of the list items so just put it before your google list item.